# how to tag a facebook profile from graph api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala, koala-gem

I want to post to a facebook page through API. I created a access token in the [graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname). I am able to successfully post to a page. I am trying to mention a person I am not able to. The old `@[id:name]` is not working. But there seems to be a way with [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions). But the issue is I am not able to tag because it wants me to enable tagging in `actiontypes`.

> After enabliing Tags in the Action Types section of the App Dashboard, add a tags parameter to your action publishing call, where tags is a comma separated list of tagging tokens for each person. These tagging tokens are retrieved using the /user/taggable_friends Graph API edge.

When I click the link for action types it asks me for a app but it is not showing graph api. Is there something fundamentally wrong with what I am trying. How to proceed? I am using the Koala gem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but if you want to tag some friends within a post, you should use the `/me/taggable_friends` endpoint to get a list of friends:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/taggable_friends/

Then, you can use those to fill the `message_tags` of the respective post:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post

Comment: The post will be done for a page. I will be tagging a artist like say Taylor Swift and say her song is playing now. So they can be anyone not just friends.

Comment: You can only tags other pages in page posts, not user profiles.